# Use list-Element in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

So below you can see my given XML. I matched the template and I'm already in the Student-node (`xsl:template match="Class/Student"`):

```
<Class>
    <Heading>This is a sentence.</Heading>
    <Student>Alex</Student>
    <Student>Emilia</Student>
    <Student>John</Student>
</Class>
```

Now I need to get a list out of all Students and what I want to get should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Alex</li>
    <li>Emilia</li>
    <li>John</li>
</ul>
```

I think I have a mistake in the way I am thinking, because my XSLT looks like this at the moment:

```
<xsl:template match="Class/Student">
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="../Student">
            <li>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

But what I actually get is:

```
<ul>
    <li>Alex</li>
    <li>Emilia</li>
    <li>John</li>
<ul>
<ul>
    <li>Alex</li>
    <li>Emilia</li>
    <li>John</li>
<ul>
<ul>
    <li>Alex</li>
    <li>Emilia</li>
    <li>John</li>
<ul>
```

I think the problem is the for-each I use but I have no idea what else I should do in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Excellent job making your first question clearly illustrate your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your positive feedback :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already made the step to use template matching with the `template match="Class/Student"` I would suggest to stick with that approach and simply write two templates, one for the `Class` elements, the other for the `Student` elements

```
  <xsl:template match="Class">
      <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Student"/>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Student">
      <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>
```

For more complex cases this results in cleaner and more modular code.

Comment: Where my answer focused on explaining why your code wasn't working, Martin's answer shows you the ideal solution.  When writing XSLT, it is best to leverage pattern matching as much as possible as Martin does here.  (+1)  Notice in particular the simplicity and independence of the two templates.  Loops are ok, but this declarative representation is elegant.

Comment: I tried both solutions and i have to admit that i prefer this one, because this fits better into my stylesheet. thank you both for these answers!

Answer (score 3):

You want one `ul` per `Class`, not per `Student`, so change

```
<xsl:template match="Class/Student">
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="Class">
```

Then change

```
    <xsl:for-each select="../Student">
```

to

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Student">
```

to get one `li` per `Student` child element of the `Class` current node.

Comment: Of course you are right. Was actually my bad but thank you so much it worked!